# Append ruby partial in javascript, and pass a rails variable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Creating a chat component with ActionCable in Rails5.  I learned today that render partial, even in .js.erb does supposedly doesn't work. `render` specifically is the issue.  So now I'm trying to call a partial, and pass a ruby variable to it.

I have tried many things, currently this is how I'm trying to accomplish it:

```
chatbox.append(<%= j (Erubis::Eruby.new(File.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'app/views/msgs',
        '_msg.html.erb'))).result(msg: @msg)) %>);
```

and the error is

```
 undefined method `self_or_other' for #<Erubis::Eruby:0x007f832bbb8590>
```

So the partial is there, but the variable is not correct.

---

views/msgs/_msg.html.erb

```
<li class="<%=  self_or_other(msg) %>">
  <div class="avatar">
    <%# if msg_interlocutor(msg).avatar.url(:thumb) == "thumb/missing.png" %>
    <%= image_tag(msg_interlocutor(msg).avatar.url(:thumb), class: "convoPic")%>
</div>
</li>
```

I also tried:

```
chatbox.append(<%= j (Msg.new(File.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'app/views/msgs',
        '_msg.html.erb'))).result(msg: @msg)) %>);
```

And get this error:
`When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.`

Trying with render:

```
App.msgs = App.cable.subscriptions.create('MsgsChannel', {  
  received: function(data) {
    var chatbox = "#chatbox_" + data.convo + " .chatboxcontent"
    var id = data.convo;
    var sender_id = data.user.id;
    var reciever_id = data.receiver;
    <%= @msg %> = data.msg
    $(chatbox).append("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'msgs/msg', :locals => { :msg => @msg }) %>");

    chatbox.scrollTop(chatbox[0].scrollHeight);
  },
  renderMsg: function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  }
});
```

And error I receive:

```
undefined method `render' for #<#<Class:0x007fe976b5c180>:0x007fe9773ed470>
```

How do I properly call in a partial, pass it a ruby variable (with the msg record). Thank you!!

Comment: Render partial should work. `chatbox.append("<%= j render(:partial => 'msgs/msg') %>");`

Comment: The error is talking about something other than the `msg` variable. Also, you shouldn't need to pass variables in this way, you can try passing `binding` and then accessing the instance variables from the partial (which are shared)

Comment: @HoMan it doesn't work. Do you know another way?

Comment: @maxple feel free to post an answer, with something I can try

Comment: Why are you using this erubis eruby method and not rails standard render?

Comment: @maxple I updated my question

Comment: @maxple unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem. Please let me know if you have a solution to the problem above. Thanks!

Comment: `<%= @msg %> = data.msg` this is not going to work, because the ERB is only evaluated when the server sends the page and the Javascript is continually running on the browser.

Comment: @maxple okay, thank you so much for the explanation - I'll try to figure out  another way.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a "messages_helper.rb" file with the following

```
module MessagesHelper
  def self_or_other(message)
    message.user == current_user ? "self" : "other"
  end

  def message_interlocutor(message)
    message.user == message.conversation.sender ? message.conversation.sender : message.conversation.recipient
  end
end
```

This is where it's defined.